# how to merge array with the same value in smarty?

Tags: arrays, smarty

i have two arrays and i want two merge using the same value within each array..

the first array is :

```
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [uid] => 0090000157
            [cid] => 0090000007
            [extension] => 202
            [secret] => Myojyo42f!
            [leader] => 1
            [simultaneous] => 
            [confbridge_id] => 2
            [created_at] => 2015-07-26 12:20:20
            [updated_at] => 2015-07-26 12:20:20
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [uid] => 0090000159
            [cid] => 0090000007
            [extension] => 
            [secret] => Myojyo42f!
            [leader] => 
            [simultaneous] => 
            [confbridge_id] => 2
            [created_at] => 2015-07-26 14:23:41
            [updated_at] => 2015-07-26 14:23:41
        )

)
```

and the second array is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [_id] => 55b52f4c2bab38fc63b6272a
            [event] => ConfbridgeJoin
            [channel] => SIP/peer_voip301confbridge-0000001b
            [uniqueid] => 1437937478.63
            [conference] => 0090000156
            [calleridnum] => 0090000157
            [calleridname] => 0090000157
            [__v] => 0
            [sipSetting] => Array
                (
                    [accountcode] => 
                    [accountcode_naisen] => 202
                    [extentype] => 0
                    [extenrealname] => 
                    [name] => 0090000157
                    [secret] => Myojyo42f!
                    [username] => 0090000157
                    [context] => innercall_xdigit
                    [gid] => 101
                    [cid] => 0090000007
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [_id] => 55b53a2e2bab38fc63b6272b
            [event] => ConfbridgeJoin
            [channel] => SIP/peer_voip301confbridge-0000001c
            [uniqueid] => 1437940260.66
            [conference] => 0090000156
            [calleridnum] => 0090000158
            [calleridname] => UID2
            [__v] => 0
            [sipSetting] => Array
                (
                    [accountcode] => 
                    [accountcode_naisen] => 203
                    [extentype] => 0
                    [extenrealname] => 
                    [name] => 0090000158
                    [secret] => Myojyo42f!
                    [username] => 0090000158
                    [context] => innercall_xdigit
                    [gid] => 101
                    [cid] => 0090000007
                )

        )

)
```

i want to merge array with the same value for example :

first array has = [uid] => 0090000157
second array has = [calleridnum] => 0090000157

is it possible to merge them?

[image]

this is my code

```
{foreach from=$participants item=participant key=p }
  {foreach from=$conference_participants item=conference_participant key=c}
            {if$participants.calleridnum == $conference_participants.uid}
              //how to get data here   ?    

            {/if}
  {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Are the comparing fields always the same? Then you could loop through both arrays and keep a list of indexes and merge them after you checked.

Comment: yes yes.. but how can i do it . . i put my code

Comment: Plain PHP is allowed in smarty, right? Also which of the two is mandetory? the first one and the second one should be just adding up to the first without overwriting values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this be what you're looking for?

**Sorry for all the changes, I should have tested it... grr**

(I've put this in PHPFiddle:

```
<pre>
<?php
$participants = [
    [   'calleridnum' => 1,
        'test' => 'yay' 
    ]
];
$conferance_participants = [
    [   'uid' => 1,
        'test' => 'yay2',
        'dit' => 'deze'
    ]
];

foreach ($participants as $participant=>$p) {
    foreach ($conferance_participants as $conferance_participant=>$c) {

        if ($p['calleridnum'] == $c['uid']) {

            // ID's match do the magic here
            foreach ( $c as $key=>$val ) {
                if (!isset($p[$key])) {
                    // Value is new, copy the conferance_participant to the participant
                    $participants[$participant][$key] = $val;
                }
            } // Merging data

        } // If: Match

    } 
}

print_r( $participants );
?>
```

)

Comment: @arem You are very welcome, oh and if you want to merge everything except for the `uid` field you can extend the `if` statement to: `if (!isset($p[$key]) && $key != 'uid') {`